# NDK in Android studio with experimental gradle 0.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-plugin

I want to use NDK in Android Studio. For that i am following the Experimental gradle
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental
I need to get NDK path in my project -> app -> build.gradle

But when I am trying it like this :-

`def ndkDir = plugins.getPlugin('com.android.model.application').getNdkFolder()`

Gradle build fails  with the following error :-

> Error:(75, 0) No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.model.AppComponentModelPlugin.getNdkFolder() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Can anyone tell me the correct way to proceed with it ?

I am using :-

- Android Studio 1.3
- Gradle2.5
  "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip"
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'

Comment: Do you need the path explicitly or just trying to configure the ndk? If the second one - `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> ` - https://0d9321c1-a-db1c6dfe-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview/ndk-install-link.png?attachauth=ANoY7crzFQgMOTlcqeS-p52K9EeEii12XWBJJTvzg3AM-Ia-nsTP2hwqXb9iiLfZplq_MglPv2vEWtXm_fsVJFrCyXBqIVVB3JeN14MuNzIxye-hKIpv8nQFt12TeiBCrImsOXgolh5f9yndG0xJ_rHau-YNSCNHshT16_6yJZPTs6kZdNt6E0PB80ZpzSKvPp4_ohG8LyTmbEf3QB6pUiRQf6AAGxEhB2V0ZmhTh5RSCrrVJW8q0et4xDcuLvGtz1OFP0MwWgbS&attredirects=0

Comment: Actually in the :app:build.gradle , I am trying to do the following :-                

// Build native code using mk files like on Eclipse
`task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = plugins.getPlugin('com.android.model.application').getNdkFolder()
    println plugins.getPlugin('com.android.model.library').getNdkFolder()

    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'}`

Comment: P.S -  I have already set up the SDK Location in the Project Structure.

Answer (score 1):

I had not a similar problem, but a related one, I think..

Try `File->settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Gradle` and select `Use default gradle wrapper`.

That did it for me. Apparently changing distributionUrl isn't enough..

Edit:

Also, the latest update bundles the NDK with the SDK. Open the SDK Manager, and download the `NDK bundle` from there. I've seen numerous cases where that simple change did the trick.
Also, why don't you just type in the static path to your NDK, which will cause your problem to go away?...

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have specified the NDK path statically in the build.gradle

`def ndkDir = '/path/to/ndk'`

with this gradle sync is successful.

Comment: Great! For the sake of other users who encounter the same problem, you might consider accepting your or my answer, So they can see this Q was solved, and act accordingly.